# How do you expand this function around infinity?

Tags: taylor-expansion, laurent-series

How do you expand this function at n= $\infty$?
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x)
 = \exp \left( - \left( \frac{x}{n + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{0.1}{n+1}} \right)^2 \left( n+ \frac{1}{6} \right) \right)
\end{align*}
$$ 
From Wolfram alpha I got
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x)= 1 - \frac{x^2}{n} + \frac{x^4+x^2}{2n^2} + \mathcal{O} (n^{-3})
\end{align*}
$$
$\\$
When I expand the exponent using Wolfram alpha I got:

$$
\begin{align*}
- \frac{x^2}{n} + \frac{x^2}{2n^2} + \mathcal{O} (n^{-3})
\end{align*}
$$

Then by taking the exponential on this term and using Taylor expansion $ \left(\exp(x) = 1+ x + \frac{x^2}{2} +\mathcal{O}(n^{-3}) \right)$ I get : $$ \begin{align*} f(x) &= 1- \frac{x^2}{n} + \frac{x^2}{2n^2} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x^4}{n^2} + \frac{x^4}{4n^4} - \frac{x^4}{n^3} \right) + \mathcal{O} (n^{-3}) \\ &= 1- \frac{x^2}{n} + \frac{x^4+x^2}{2n^2} + \mathcal{O} (n^{-3}) \end{align*} $$
Where I in the second equality have collected the same order terms under the big-O.

Comment: Can you write what did you try?

Comment: I tried using $\exp(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + ... $

Comment: When expanding the exponent using Wolfram alpha you get: $ - \frac{x^2}{n} + \frac{x^2}{2n^2} + \mathcal{O} (n^{-3})$.

Comment: Then by taking the exponential on this term and using Taylor expansion I get: $$ \begin{align*} f(x) &= 1- \frac{x^2}{n} + \frac{x^2}{2n^2} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x^4}{n^2} + \frac{x^4}{4n^4} - \frac{x^4}{n^3} \right) + \mathcal{O} (n^{-3}) \\ &= 1- \frac{x^2}{n} + \frac{x^4+x^2}{2n^2} + \mathcal{O} (n^{-3}) \end{align*} $$

Comment: you can edit your question, it would be simpler to understand there

Answer (score 1):

$$f
 = \exp \left( - \left( \frac{x}{n + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{10(n+1)}} \right)^2 \left( n+ \frac{1}{6} \right) \right)$$
$$\log(f)=- \left( \frac{x}{n + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{10(n+1)}} \right)^2 \left( n+ \frac{1}{6} \right)=-x^2\frac {n+\frac{1}{6}}{\left(n + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{10(n+1)} \right)^2} $$ Now, using long division or Taylor series
$$\frac {n+\frac{1}{6}}{\left(n + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{10(n+1)} \right)^2}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{1}{45
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$\log(f)=-\frac{x^2}{n}+\frac{x^2}{2 n^2}-\frac{x^2}{45
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ Now, using $f=e^{\log(f)}$ and Taylor again
$$f=1-\frac{x^2}{n}+\frac{x^2+x^4}{2 n^2}-\frac{2 x^2+45 x^4+15 x^6}{90 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$